# Excel how to take text from 2 spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

i need to search no value on spreadsheet1 and return me the name in the first colon on spreadsheet 2.

Like example below.

Thank you

```
Spreadsheet1



 A         B         C          D
 Name      Surname   Address    Exist
 Jhon       Doe       Dummy      Yes
 Pamela     Summer    Dummy      No
 Sam        Doe        Dummy      Yes
 Jacob      Summer     Dummy      No



Spreadsheet 2

   A
1 Search if in Spreadsheet1 D there are No text then return me "Pamela" value from first column
2 Search if in Spreadsheet1 D there are No text then return me "Jacob" value from first column
3 ecc..
4
```

Comment: Have you tried anything with `Match()` or `Offset()` yet? Do you want to use worksheet functions, or use macros and VBA?

Comment: it's possible only worksheet function

Comment: Homework questions are expected to show original effort. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can pass the corrrect row number to the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) by turning anything that does not match into an error and ignoring errors.

Use the formula from the image's F7 in Sheet2!A1 and fill down.

[image: index_aggregate_second]

The wrapping [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) default the formula return to **ecc..** when no further matches can be found although I'm unclear on wht that was important.

Answer (score 0):

In Spreadsheet 2 put the following formula

```
   A
1 =IF(Sheet1!D2="No";Sheet1!A2;"")
2 =IF(Sheet1!D3="No";Sheet1!A3;"")
3 =IF(Sheet1!D4="No";Sheet1!A4;"")
4 =IF(Sheet1!D5="No";Sheet1!A5;"")
5 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will be able to **run the macro** then use this:

```
Option Compare Text

Sub findNo()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim indx As Integer

indx = 1
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("D1:D" & lastrow)

For Each cell In rng
     If cell.Text = "no" Then
        Sheet2.Cells(indx, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(cell.Row, 1)
        indx = indx + 1
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

**However if the worksheet formula usage is the only available way** then you can use solution proposed by aPhilRa but that will leave you with plenty of empty rows that you cannot easily delete. Returned "" makes the cell to look like empty but you cannot use ctrl+G-->special-->blanks to select them as they are no longer truly empty.

Alternative is to use altered version of the formula that returns something else instead of "", like formula error:

`=IF(Sheet1!D2="No";Sheet1!A2;na())
 =IF(Sheet1!D3="No";Sheet1!A3;na())
 =IF(Sheet1!D4="No";Sheet1!A4;na())
 =IF(Sheet1!D5="No";Sheet1!A5;na())`

This will result in #N/A when different text than "no" is used on sheet1 and you can easily select all those cells by ctrl+G-->special-->Formulas errors to delete them in single action if needed.